# How long should I blanch baby peas?

Tags: vegetables, blanching

I have a recipe which calls for a cup of blanched baby peas.

Now, I know what blanching is. It concerns cooking the outer layer of green vegetables (James Peterson), but how long should I blanch baby peas?

It seems that even a few seconds would cook them all the way through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

15-20 seconds seems to be all it needs for me, and then scoop them up and shock them in iced water to stop them cooking.